# Best way to auto-synchronise music between HTC One and PC

Tags: sync, music

got my new HTC One today and now i wanted to set up something that i can put all my desired music for the smartphone in a folder on the pc and then they get automatically synchronised on the smartphone.

is this possible? i often change my songs and i dont want to always copy them by hand, thats a pain...

Jottacloud has something in the right direction, but it isnt fully automated i guess

Comment: Google Play Music?

Comment: first of all its not available in switzerland, and i think you must have bought the music there, right?

Comment: No, you can use Google Music Manager on your PC to upload all your music to Google, and then stream it to your phone over the Internet.

Comment: hmm ok, but i wanna have something that stores the file permanently to the phone's sd-card

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing with words: if you want a folder to sync, have you tried [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite)? Should be perfect for this purpose. You can sync entire folders between your PC and your Android device, and also use different cloud storage services. Thanks to an integrated *Tasker/Locale* plugin (in the [full version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full)), you also can automate it to your wishes. But even without *Tasker/Locale*, it offers *User specified sync interval or specific sync times*.

Comment: nice, does all what i need. thx!

Comment: Always glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Winamp for Android also has a sync music capability. You would however need to install Winamp on your PC and configure it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Style Jukebox. It's a cross-platform music app that stores your music and playlists in the Cloud and lets you listen to it on all your devices. It's like Dropbox for music and you start from 2000 songs for free.

You can get Style Jukebox at get-jukebox.com

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Are you affiliated to this software in any way? If so you are required to mention this is your answer.

Comment: tryed it out now, the idea behind it is good, but it's a bit more like in beta-status. With bigger improvements this could get really big, for now i will still use FolderSync