# Sync photos with PC

Tags: sync, photos

I am looking for a solution that syncs the photos on my Android phone to a folder on my PC. Samsung Kies doesn't sync photos all it does is just make a backup. I've looked at other solutions and cant seem to find an app that will take my pics and sync them with a folder on my PC and save them like my camera application does in Year>Month>Day folders. Is there such an app that truly syncs like this?

Comment: You might wish to take a look at [Best way to auto-synchronise music between HTC One and PC](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46269/16575). Never mind it's "music files" there, and you're after photos: files are files, in this context :)

Answer (score 1):

[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com#learn-more) is great for syncing photos on your mobile device to any connect computer. Dropbox also has up to 26GB of free space. I personally use Dropbox with my family to share photos and information with them.

Comment: Yeah but you have to specify a single folder right?